# The LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80040E14

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

installed an SQL Server 2012 x64 on an Server 2012 x64 without domain. The server is just in the workgroup WORKGROUP as default setting.

I created the  package "import cards" which imports some csv files into a database. In BIDS, the package works fine without trouble. The package also write some logfiles when the package start, end and on errors.

With the Execute Package Utility the package works fine too.

Now i import the package in the msdb database as an file system import and the protection level "Keep protection level of the original package".

my last step was creating a schedule, as usual. Trying to running the schedule drives me nuts.

My SQL Server Agent is started with the account "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" The User properties has a mapping to the msdb database including the roll "ssisadmin".

I read this in my meaning very useful [post](http://databaseandstorage.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/the-loadfromsqlserver-method-has.html).

But the Schedule wont working.
Error message in History:

```
Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute 
Package Utility      Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
All rights reserved.    Started:  2:38:18 PM  Could not load package "\importCards" 
because of error 0xC0014062.  Description: The LoadFromSQLServer method has 
encountered OLE DB error code 0x80040E14 (Only the owner of DTS Package 'importCards' 
or a member of the sysadmin role may create new versions of it.).  The SQL statement 
that was issued has failed.  Source:   Started:  2:38:18 PM  Finished: 2:38:18 PM  
Elapsed:  0.031 seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.
```

nothing works and I'm very frustrated. Perhaps you can help me. Every clue is appeciated

Thank you!

Comment: Try making NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT a sysadmin.

Comment: In the server roles, the sysadmin is checked for user SQLSERVERAGENT

Answer (score 0):

the problem therefore seems to come from inserting the step e.g. importing the package into the integration services.
I can't see the data sources of the step and as long as you see no data sources, you have no chance to run the job with success.